# Octave generating a random number with known probability

Tags: math, octave, probability

I want to generate a random number with range and with a given probability in octave but I'm not sure how to:

> 0.5 chance of 1 - 50
>
> 0.3 chance of 51 - 80
>
> 0.2 chance of 81 - 100

thx

Comment: Looks like a uniform probability if you ask me.

Comment: What a funny teacher, which gave you this homework. I guess it's to see if you understand waht you are doing or if you just copy and paste some code found in SO

Answer (score 2):

Use [`randi`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/randi.html) to generate those integers in combination with [`randsample`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/randsample.html) (from Statistics package) to define that bias.

```
pkg load statistics;
R = randsample([randi(50), randi([51 80]), randi([81 100])], 1, true, ...
                   [0.50,      0.3,        0.2]);
```

Comment: Nice! But in this particular case, with these particular weights, I think this is the same as `randi(100)`... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Oops. Didn't notice that. Using `randsample` is an overkill for these weights. But I'll leave it as is just in case if someone wants to use other weights